# Is it possible to edit my code from Visual Studio Online (VS Team Services)?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, visual-studio-monaco

I have [Visual Studio Online](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-online-overview-vs) (now VS Team Services) account as a part of my MSDN subscription. I managed to create a project there, set a workspace in my local Visual Studio 2013 and check-in some test code. I was wondering if it is also possible to edit code using the web interface instead of local VS?

Here's a screenshot for you who have not discovered this tool yet.

[image]

Comment: Is this free of charge but not a trial one?

Comment: @tech_me Find out on the Microsoft websites. Mine is a part of the MSDN subscription.

Comment: Can you do this on chromebook ?

Comment: @GutterStink It's a browser thing, so you should be able to do it.

Comment: It is solved, there is Edit button now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Visual Studio Monaco editing experience is currently available on a number of Azure Websites. A quick introduction and getting started can be found on Channel9:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-Online-Monaco

Especially the "First Steps" video walks you through the steps of setting this up:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-Online-Monaco/First-Steps

This is (not yet) available for non-azure website projects, but this is where things are heading without a doubt. I can't wait to get my hands on it.

Comment: The "Monaco" editor is actually hosted in Visual Studio Online when you are looking at source code inside of the source control repository area (like in your screenshot above).  The editing portion is just not enabled yet.  You'll actually find the "Monaco" editor in other places like SkyDrive, the "Napa" tools, etc.

Comment: @EdBlankenship we can't wait for it :).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can currently, however it used Monaco editor, which is the same editor as sky drive uses for code files. So it may be that Microsoft are planning to add this in at some point.

Edit:
Turns out they are planning on adding it, at lease for azure web sites, I found this article on tech cruch:
http://techcrunch.com/2013/11/13/microsofts-visual-studio-2013-launches-with-new-online-tools-for-team-and-build-management-preview-of-browser-based-code-editor/

Answer (score 4):

It is now possible to edit code directly in your repo on VisualStudio.com. I don't know how long it's been enabled, but I have recently gone in to "correct" small typos, such as when a developer changes a connection string in web.config locally and accidentally commits it. What's really cool is that when you save the file, if it's a git repo, you can automatically create a new branch and pull request with your change at the same time. I find it to be very convenient for very small changes.

Comment: I get a security flag that says I don't have permissions.  I am site administrator.  I should have every permission.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are old but I found this through Google so I think an update is needed.

Yes, you can edit a text file in Visual Studio Team Services (formerly Visual Studio Online).

Go to Code->Files.
Select the file.
Click Edit.
Edit the file.
Click Save.

If that file is being monitored by a build definition then a build will be kicked off.

This editing is not limited to Azure Website projects. What those other posters are referring to is you can edit code that is already deployed to a website. This is different becasue it is editing code in the repo.

[image: Screenshot of edit button]

Answer (score 2):

No, visual studio online hosts your code repository in the cloud (similar to github) and provides you with a code browsing experience.

If you are referring to editing code in the cloud, see [Visual studio online "Monaco"](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-Online-Monaco), which only works on azure websites for now.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be "POSSIBLE".

Could you check this article which I have just found, which would be something you want?
http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/first-look-visual-studio
at its first section "Getting started".

Comment: That's the Monaco. They are both called VS Online because they are indeed online, but only the Monaco serves for the code editing. The other one I took screenshot from is just a viewer and TFS manager.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek Yes, it is called Monaco, but I just refer it for your question **if it is also possible to edit code using the web interface instead of local VS**, but I don't know what you want maybe a completed Online Visual Studio IDE;)

Comment: I know it's possible, but not from VS Online. Monaco allows it. But I originally thought that VS Online allows it because I had no clue that there is also the Monaco project.

Answer (score 1):

> Here you go. Try this in MSDN Offical Site for basic programs

[Microsoft Online IDE](https://www.microsoft.com/net/tutorials/csharp/getting-started)

Comment: this is better suited as comment.

Answer (score -3):

One solution that I use is to create a small V/M either on Amazon AWS, Azure (or any other cloud service) and install Visual Studio on there, then RDC into the V/M.  You can spin up the V/M whenever you need to or if it's on a high-availability instance, you can connect any time.

Using TFS online with this is great, as I can either work locally, in a disconnected state (traveling, etc.), check-in, then work on the cloud, and really never have to carry my laptop around.