# Possible to add/edit workitems inside Visual Studio when using VSTS/VSOnline?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying out Visual Studio Online, and have setup my project, and it's working pretty good. But I prefer working on workitems directly in Visual Studio (it's faster, and it's what I'm used to). Is it possible to configure Visual Studio to access and edit workitems in the IDE as opposed to opening up the web version in an external window?

Comment: Quite an off-topic question but if you go into tools, and at the bottom of that menu, click options. then scroll until you see "Work Items", click that then "Open work items in: Visual Studio (compatibility mode)". To make a work item in VS, click "Team" then "New Work Item"

Comment: @L_Church Asking about software tools commonly used by programmers is on-topic.

Comment: makes no sense when one of the flag options is about "general software issues"

Comment: @L_Church Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Third bullet point.

Comment: I came here from a link on VisualStudio. com, it recommended Stack Overflow as the place to ask questions about Visual Studio. There are similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978110/is-it-possible-to-edit-my-code-from-visual-studio-online-vs-team-services

Comment: @JaimiMcEntire Do you solve this issue with Daniel's solution?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT - yes, I marked it just now. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but it's going to be deprecated soon.

In Visual Studio, go to "Tools" -> "Options" and search for "Work items". There is a drop-down for "Open Work Items in", which will have an option for browser or Visual Studio.

It's better to get used to managing work items in the web; Microsoft has invested a ton of effort in making the web experience awesome. Basically, they don't want to maintain two ways of managing work items: Web and Visual Studio. Since TFS/VSTS is cross-platform and cross-technology, it doesn't make sense for them to invest effort in maintaining a work item editor built into Visual Studio. Developers use VSTS for all types of projects using all types of IDEs/ISEs, not just Visual Studio.

Comment: @L_Church This is absolutely not off-topic. It's a question about Visual Studio (and to a lesser extent, about VSTS), both of which are tools used by developers, which makes it on-topic. Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: doesnt matter if its used by devs, it's got nothing to do with actual programming... he's not trying to fix an error in some C# he's just trying to get some software to work (which mind you is what i flagged it on)

Comment: @L_Church Read the section on topics, please. Asking about software tools commonly used by programmers is absolutely on topic.

Comment: @L_Church You are incorrect. From the linked page: "What topics can I ask about here? ...if your question generally covers…
software tools commonly used by programmers;... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: eh... my logic passes that i guess. just seemed like a silly-just-google-the-bloody-thing question

Comment: @L_Church - of course I googled it first. And I searched Stack Overflow first.

Comment: @DanielMann - Thank you, I'll switch over and try to wean myself off the IDE after I get the bulk of my items set up.